# Is the gradient of point projected on sublevel set increasing?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be a convex, increasing, and continuously differentiable function, define an implicit function $g : \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ in the following manner: 
$$ g(l) = \| \nabla f(x_l)\|_2,$$ where 
\begin{align} 
x_l = \arg&\min_x \frac{1}{2} \| x - y\|_2^2 \\
\text{s.t.} \quad &  f(x) \le l.
\end{align} 
Intuitively, $x_l$ is the projection of $y$ onto the sublevel set $ K_l = \{ x \mid f(x) \le l\}$. I would like to show that the function $g(l)$ is non-decreasing, or come up with counter example that this is not true. This is trivially true when $n = 1$, but I am not sure how to show it in higher dimensions.

I have tried using the first order condition: 
$$ y - x_l = \lambda_l \nabla f(x_l), $$
where $\lambda_l$ is the optimal dual variable, hence $\|\nabla f (x_l)\| = \frac{1}{\lambda_l}\| y - x_l \|$, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: what do mean by $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ is increasing ?

Comment: It means that if $x \ge y$, then $f(x) \ge f(y)$, where $x \ge y$ means that $x - y$ is in the positive orthant, i.e., for all $i$, $x_i \ge y_i$.